# How can I position my table header on bottom on scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bulma

This is my table:

```
<table class="table tableOnScroll">
   <thead class="mobile-head-table">
         <tr>
             <td class="mobile-header-product-item-0">
                    <div class="product-item-image hideImage">
                            <div class="is-size-7 cross-sell-flag px-2 py-1 new-product-flag">
                                <p>popular</p>
                            </div>
                        <figure class="image is-4by5">
                            <img src="">
                        </figure>
                    </div>
                    <div class="promotion hidePromo">
                        <p>15% OFF with Mattress Purchase!</p>
                    </div>
                    <p class="product-name">Adjustable Memory Foam Pillow</p>
                    <div class="product-pricing">
                        <p>From</p>
                        <p class="price">79</p>

                        <div class="content is-flex mt-3">
                            <a href="" class="button is-fullwidth">
        SHOP NOW            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="mobile-header-product-item-1">
                    <div class="product-item-image hideImage">
                            <div class="is-size-7 cross-sell-flag px-2 py-1 on-sale-flag">
                                <p>BEST SELLER</p>
                            </div>
                        <figure class="image is-4by5">
                            <img src="">
                        </figure>
                    </div>
                    <div class="promotion hidePromo">
                        <p>15% OFF with Mattress Purchase!</p>
                    </div>
                    <p class="product-name">Cooling Gel Memory Foam Pillow</p>
                    <div class="product-pricing">
                        <p>From</p>
                        <p class="price">89</p>

                        <div class="content is-flex mt-3">
                            <a href="" class="button is-fullwidth">
        SHOP NOW            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody class="mobile-body-table">
            <tr class="summary is-flex-touch is-hidden-desktop">
                <td class="side-header is-flex">
                    <div class="header-text">
                    <h1>Summary</h1></div>
                </td>
            <td>
                                <div class="markdown-wrapper">
                                    An ultra-breathable memory foam pillow with a soft, responsive, cooling design. Over 50,000 sold!                                   </div>
                            </td><td>
                                <div class="markdown-wrapper">
                                    Enjoy the support and cushioning of memory foam with next-level cooling.                                    </div>
                            </td></tr>
        <tr class="feature is-flex-touch is-hidden-desktop"><td class="side-header is-flex"><div class="header-text"><img src="">Warranty</div><div class="header-summary"><p>Guaranteed worry free sleep with Douglas Pillow</p></div></td><td>
            <div class="markdown-wrapper">
                <h3>3</h3> 

<p>Years</p>

            </div>
        </td><td>
            <div class="markdown-wrapper">
                <h3>4</h3> 

<p>Years</p>

            </div>
        </td></tr><tr class="feature is-flex-touch is-hidden-desktop"><td class="side-header is-flex"><div class="header-text"><img src="">Free Shipping &amp; Returns</div><div class="header-summary"><p>Your Douglas Pillow will be delivered free of charge</p></div></td><td>
            <div class="markdown-wrapper">
                <p><img src=""></p>

<p>Included</p>

            </div>
        </td><td>
            <div class="markdown-wrapper">
                <p><img src=""></p>

<p>Included</p>

            </div>
        </td></tr><tr class="feature is-flex-touch is-hidden-desktop"><td class="side-header is-flex"><div class="header-text"><img src="">Coolness</div></td><td>
            <div class="markdown-wrapper">
                <p><img src=""></p>

            </div>
        </td><td>
            <div class="markdown-wrapper">
                <p><img src=""></p>

<p>Single action graphic</p>

            </div>
        </td></tr>
        </tbody>

        <tfoot class="mobile-footer-table">
            <tr>
                <td class="side-header">
                    Other Features                  </td>
                <td>
                                        <p>Adjustable Firmness</p>

                                        <p>Supportive</p>

                                        <p>Fit all pillows</p>

                                        <p>Back Sleepers</p>

                                        <p>Side Sleepers</p>

                                        <p>Cooling Technology</p>

                                        <p>Improved Memory Foam</p>

                                        <p>Improved Memory Foam</p>

                                    </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>            
</table>
```

I tried this css

```
thead {
 position: sticky;
 bottom: 0;
 z-index: 99;
}
```

and this did not work at all so I tried this instead

```
thead {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 z-index: 99;
}
```

and it worked but the only problem is that once the content of the table is completed and when the other sections start coming, the position of the thead remain the same which makes sense.

I either want the table header to be sticky on bottom on scroll and disappear as soon as the other content comes up or with the second css code provided, if it's possible to reset the position again as other sections start coming up.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: There are two common scenarios where a position: sticky element will not stick to the window as intended:

No inset property has been defined: Make sure the sticky element has top or bottom set. Or in the case of horizontal scrolling, left or right.

One of the element’s ancestors has incompatible overflow: If any of the parents or ancestors of the sticky element have overflow set to hidden, scroll, or auto. This also applies to overflow-x and overflow-y.

Read from: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/css-position-sticky

Answer (score 0):

add js to element:

```js
const header = document.getElementById("headerid");

onScroll() {
  header.style.position = "static"
  console.log("Changed Position")
}
```

Add a id of `headerid` to the header, than set the onScroll attribute of the element to run the function onScroll(), which changes the position to normal. To do the opposite copy the function and change "static" to "fixed" and add the line `header.style.bottom = 0;`. Hope this fixes your problem!

Comment: Can you give an example code of this please? It did not entirely make sense to me and I am unsure on how to apply this